# How do you get a list of Invalidation Requests from the Amazon Cloudfront .NET API?

Tags: c#, .net, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I've referenced [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/ListInvalidation.html) section in the API documentation, but I'm not sure if the request I'm sending out via the API is correct. This is what my code looks like:

```
public class CfListInvalidation
{
    string accessKeyID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["awsAccessID"];
    string secretAccessKeyID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["awsSecretAnswer"];
    string distributionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["distributionId"];
    AmazonCloudFront client;

    public void SendCommand()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Amazon Cloud Front...");   

        using (client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudFrontClient(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID))
        {
            ListInvalidationsResult result = new ListInvalidationsResult();

            IAsyncResult r = client.BeginListInvalidations(new ListInvalidationsRequest
            {
                DistributionId = distributionId,                                        
            }, new AsyncCallback(CfListInvalidation.CompleteRead), result );                

        }
    }

    static void CompleteRead(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ListInvalidationsResult r = result.AsyncState as ListInvalidationsResult;

        if (r != null && r.InvalidationList != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("listing items..");

            foreach (InvalidationSummary s in r.InvalidationList.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID: {0} - Status: {1}", s.Id, s.Status));
            }
        }

        else {
            Console.WriteLine("No Items Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you encountered any problem or do you just want to ensure your approach is correct?

Answer (score 1):

When using Begin* methods, you need to call the matching End* method to complete the request and retrieve the result object. Take a look at [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/sdk-net-async-api.html) for a number of examples.

Here's a simplified sample from the guide that illustrates the basic approach:

```
// Begin method
client.BeginPutObject(request, CallbackWithClient, client);

// Callback
public static void CallbackWithClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
  AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client) asyncResult.AsyncState;
  PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.EndPutObject(asyncResult);

  // Process the response
}
```